# python parsing wifi SSID data

Tags: python, parsing, wifi

I currently have the following. But I have noticed that if a SSID includes a space the ordering goes off:

```
import subprocess
import csv

process = subprocess.Popen(['/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport', '-s'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()

reader = csv.DictReader(stdout.decode('ascii').splitlines(),
                        delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True,
                        fieldnames=['wifi_name', 'mac', 'strength'])

for row in reader:
    print(row)
```

My objective is to get the SSID, mac address and signal strength stored so it can be compared to a spreadsheet.

Comment: I had a look using awk '{print $1;}' and it is the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `airport --help`:

```
-x        --xml                Print info as XML
```

Which will output the information in Apple's XML format for property lists, which should be parsable more reliably. Python even comes with a [`plistlib`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/plistlib.html) module which can parse the XML into a Python dictionary:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from plistlib import readPlist
from pprint import pprint

AirportPath = '/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport'

proc = Popen([AirportPath, '-s', '-x'], stdout=PIPE)

ssid_data = readPlist(proc.stdout)
pprint(ssid_data)
```

Comment: would I use `xml.etree` for this... just checking I'm on the right track :)

Comment: @user969617: Python comes with a library for reading plists, I'll edit it into the answer.

Comment: Apologies for the stupid question, but how do I go about this? If I save the xml file I can then use `from plistlib import readPlist` `pl = readPlist('/Users/name/Library/Scripts/wifiinfo')` `print(pl[1])` but can I do it without saving the file first?

Comment: The [docs for `readPlist`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/plistlib.html#plistlib.readPlist) say: "`pathOrFile` may either be a file name or a (readable) file object". The stdout of a process *should* count as a "readable file".